# Error "Unknown repository for package source: bitbucket" when deploying Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, bitbucket, shinyapps

I'm trying to deploy a Shiny app that use disgenet2r library.

Everything works in local but when I try to deploy the app on shinyapps.io, I have the following error message:

"Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1144908236 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unknown repository for package source: bitbucket"

I had the same with Bioconductor but options(repos = BiocManager::repositories()) solved it. But I don't know how to do it with bitbucket (I only installed disgenet2r, I don't have anything like bitbucket event if, if I understand correctly, disgenet2s "come" from bitbucket).

Do you have any clue about this? Sorry if my question is stupid, I'm still learning.

Thank you!

Comment: Shinyapps.io does not currently support Bitbucket repositories. More from the user guide (see Package Sources): 
https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud
This is because package installation is handled by the server. You can't call `install.packages()` or `devtools::install_bitbucket()` or `devtools::install_git()` on the bitbucket git repo URL in a shinyapps.io app.

Comment: If you run your own shiny server, you can install whatever packages you would like. However if you are using the shinyapps platform you are out of luck

Comment: Thank you so much @AndrewBrown! It is very clear. I'll try with my own shiny server then. Have a nice day.